Minimal changes to harvard style citation
I'm trying to switch my citation to Harvard style (\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,style=authoryear]{biblatex}).
A requirement is, that the sources are formatted as follows in-line

(Author, year, page number).

Currently, "Author" is in non-italic letters, and not followed by a comma.
Is there a quick way to change this?

A longer example:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,style=authoryear]{biblatex} 
\bibliography{sample}  
\begin{document}   
\section{Demonstration}  
Lorem ipsum (\cite{GMP81}).  
\printbibliography  
\end{document} 

with
@inproceedings{GMP81,
    author = "Mark Goresky and Robert MacPherson",
    title = "On the topology of complex algebraic maps",
    booktitle = "Algebraic Geometry Proceedings, La R\'abida,              
                 Lecture Notes in Mathematics",
    number = 961, 
    year = 1981}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short TeX code with one Bib-entry resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

@Mensch
`\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{sample}
\begin{document}
\section{Demonstration}
Lorem ipsum (\cite{GMP81}).
\printbibliography
\end{document}`
with
@inproceedings{GMP81,    author = "Mark Goresky and Robert MacPherson",     title = "On the topology of complex algebraic maps", booktitle = "Algebraic Geometry Proceedings, La R\'abida,              Lecture Notes in Mathematics",    number = 961,      year = 1981}
results in Goresky and MacPherson 1981)

@Mensch but the wanted output is (Goresky and MacPherson, 1981).

@JulianK - I've taken the  liberty of copying (and pretty-printing) your code from the comment into the body of your query.

@Mico Thank you!

This is as easy as adjusting the name wrapper format for labelname and the nameyeardelim delimiter.
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{labelname}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}



Simple and perfect - thank you so much!
